# Implementing a horizonatal <div> carousel using prototype.js and scriptaculouas

Tags: javascript, scriptaculous, prototypejs

I need to implement a carousel of 5 divs with 3 that appear and two the are off screen. I want to cycle through the divs with arrows so that they move around like a carousel.

I know you can do this with jQuery - but I'm limited to using prototype.js and scriptaculous.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

check out the implementation of

http://miedlar.com/dev/carousel

http://scripteka.com/script/prototype-carousel